# Why IE 64-bit is not getting installed on my 64-bit OS

Tags: internet-explorer

I go to Internet Explorer 9 website and select 64-bit version and install it. I have a Windows 7 64-bit. But when I look at it in Task Manager it is showing it as 32-bit.
What is going on?

Comment: You still have the 32-bit version installed as well, so you have to be careful not to select the "wrong" IE icon or menu option.

Answer (score 7):

When you install the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer, it also installs the 32-bit version. To use the 64-bit version, you have to find the `Internet Explorer (64-bit)` shortcut in your Start Menu.

[image: Internet Explorer]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved. the trick is that it installs it in both ProgramFiles(x86) folder and also in Program Files folder which is 64-bit but the default short-cut link when you click on IE icon is pointing to 32-bit so we should change that to pint to Program Files folder that is 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall IE.  Then reinstall using the file you downloaded from Internet Explorer 9's website.